# сериализация в windows form C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, xml, serialize, serializable

Создал базу данных на С#, данные, которые ввожу в DGV, хочу сохранить в XML файл. Код работает, но в XML файле записывает пустые поля. Новичок, подскажите, что не так.

```
[Serializable]
public class friends
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }    
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        
    public string LastName { get; set; }        
    public int Age { get; set; }        
    public string Number { get; set; }        
    public int House { get; set; }       
    public string Adress { get; set; }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//////импорт в XML
{
    friends p1= new friends();
    XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(friends));
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\book.xml",
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        serial.Serialize(fs, p1);
        MessageBox.Show("XML was created");
    }
}
```

Вот такой код в XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<friends xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Id>0</Id>
  <Age>0</Age>
  <House>0</House>
</friends>
```

Обработка добавление даннх

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//////////////add information
    {
        Form2 friendForm = new Form2();
        DialogResult result = friendForm.ShowDialog(this);

        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        friends friends = new friends();
        friends.FirstName = friendForm.textBox1.Text;
        friends.LastName = friendForm.textBox2.Text;
        friends.Age = (int)friendForm.numericUpDown1.Value;
        friends.Number = friendForm.textBox3.Text;
        friends.House = (int)friendForm.numericUpDown2.Value;
        friends.Adress = friendForm.textBox4.Text;

        db.friendsSet.Add(friends);
        db.SaveChanges();

        MessageBox.Show("refresh");
    }
```

Comment: И как связан этот код с предыдущим? Тут добавление в БД, а не xml. И вообще, задавайте лучше несколько маленьких, но конкретных вопросов, чем один всеобъемлющий.

Comment: ну суть в тому что у меня есть база данных. Допустим я добавляю несколько полей в DGV, а потом мне нужно в обработчике событие(Import in XML) все те данные что были в DGV импортировать в XML файл. типа работа з базой данных и XML файлом. Извините,что тупо задал вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В коде создаётся новый объект и тут же сериализуется. Конечно, сразу после создания все его свойства равны значениям по умолчанию, т. е. `null` и `0`.

Данные тем или иным образом сперва должны быть перенесены из `DataGridView` в этот объект, и лишь затем его нужно сохранять.

---

Просто объедините ваши участки кода:

```
friends friends = new friends();
friends.FirstName = friendForm.textBox1.Text;
friends.LastName = friendForm.textBox2.Text;
friends.Age = (int)friendForm.numericUpDown1.Value;
friends.Number = friendForm.textBox3.Text;
friends.House = (int)friendForm.numericUpDown2.Value;
friends.Adress = friendForm.textBox4.Text;

db.friendsSet.Add(friends);
db.SaveChanges();

XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(friends));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\book.xml",
    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    serial.Serialize(fs, friends);
    MessageBox.Show("XML was created");
}
```

Создаётся экземпляр `friends`, его свойства заполняются, затем он сохраняется в БД и в xml-файл.

---

Кстати, название класса должно с большой буквы. И, так как это информация об одном друге, то оно должно быть в единственном числе: `Friend`.

Comment: Понял, но как мне исправить первую ошибку не могу понять? я данные добавляю з другой подформы, вот обрабочик кнопки

Comment: я делал так как Igor написал ниже, но ето только в коде, а мне надо когда динамичеки я добавляю в грид чтото сразу можу импортировать в XML

Comment: @OleksandrPavlyshyn - дополнил ответ.

Comment: это да, но при каждом нажатие на кнопку (add information), предыдущая запис будет удалена, а новая перезапишется, тоисть будет не более одной записи в XML

Comment: @OleksandrPavlyshyn - задайте **новый** вопрос: "Как добавлять информацию в xml-файл".

Comment: Окей. большое спасибо за информацию